# Matlab: integrate function in dependence of a parameter

Tags: matlab

I am a matlab beginner and can not spot the mistake in the following code:

> `a=0.5;
>   b=0.5;
>   f=@(u,x) exp(-x.^2/2)*(2*pi).^(-1/2)*exp(log(a+b.*x.^2).*u);
>   t=0:0.1:1;
>   g=0*t;
>   for i=1:numel(t)
>       fab=@(x) f(t(i),x);
>       g(i)=quadgk(fab,-inf,inf);
>   end
>   surf(t,g)`

Where is the format wrong? I really do not get it. I want to plot the value of a integral in dependence of a parameter.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Two things. First, add some more `.`, if you use

> `f=@(u,x) exp(-x.^2/2).*(2*pi).^(-1/2).*exp(log(a+b.*x.^2).*u);`

`f` works as it should. Second, `surf` does not work for 1d-plots, use `plot`, giving

> `a=0.5;
>   b=0.5;
>   f=@(u,x) exp(-x.^2/2).*(2*pi).^(-1/2).*exp(log(a+b.*x.^2).*u); 
>   t=0:0.1:1; 
>   g=0*t; 
>   for i=1:numel(t) 
>       fab=@(x) f(t(i),x);
>       g(i)=quadgk(fab,-inf,inf); 
>   end
>   plot(t,g)`

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I get it and will set "." everywhere in the future.